# What is the special gitlab-ci-token user?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

The docs for gitlab's container registry (https://gitlab.com/help/container_registry/README.md) provide a config example with this instruction:

`- docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.example.com`

and this explanation:

`You have to use the credentials of the special gitlab-ci-token user with its password stored in $CI_BUILD_TOKEN in order to push to the Registry connected to your project. This allows you to automated building and deployment of your Docker images.`

I cannot find any documentation about this special `gitlab-ci-token` user, nor about the `$CI_BUILD_TOKEN` var.

What is this special user? Is it automatically available? Does it have to be defined somewhere? What value should be given to the `$CI_BUILD_TOKEN` var?

Comment: The mentioned link "https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/container_registry/README.html" is dead unfortunately :(

Answer (score 19):

Gitlab acts as an authentication provider for the registry.
`gitlab-ci-token` is a user automatically created for you.
`CI_BUILD_TOKEN` is set automatically for each build by Gitlab-CI

Comment: have you actually managed to get this to work? Where did you find this information? Where is it documented?
I have just updated my gitlab CE installation and it still doesn't work.  

`echo $CI_BUILD_TOKEN` returns nothing  

```$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.xxxxx.com  
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v... unauthorized: incorrect username or password  
```

Comment: Yes I have it working:
`$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.mydomain.com
Login Succeeded`
Information can be found here:
http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/container_registry/README.html `Section Build and push images using GitLab CI`

The variable is only available within the build process, not on the machine GitLab is running on. If you want to login from there use the same credentials you use when logging into GitLab

Comment: Some useful info from the gitlab buys: gitlab runner 1.2 is required. Now it works.

Comment: And how does it login to the docker registry from the target server during deployment?

Comment: Your deployment-runner (may be a dedicated runner on that server or connecting via ssh) is injected with the credentials so it can login. If it is still unclear please provide a little more information on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

In my case [upgrading of gitlab-runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html#updating-the-runner) helped me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this worked [CI-permission](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html)

So, using user cred as gitlab-ci-token and $CI_BUILD_TOKEN which is created by them.

- The token would be readable to anyone who had Developer access to a project that could run CI jobs, allowing the developer to register any specific Runner for that project.
- The token would allow accessing only the project’s sources, forbidden from accessing any other projects.

Comment: The permission link is broken