# Use GitLab API from a GitLabCI build script

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a GitLab CI build script like this:

```
create release:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - basic
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - GITLOG=$(echo "# Changes Log"; git log `git tag | tail -2 | head -1`..${CI_BUILD_TAG} --pretty=format:" - %s")
    - curl -X POST -d "private_token=$CI_BUILD_TOKEN&description=$GITLOG" "http://git.example.com/api/v3/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/repository/tags/${CI_BUILD_TAG}/release"
```

The purpose of this step is to automatically add a Changes Log from Git in the GitLab Releases section.

That works if I manually run this on the command line and put in the variables...

The problem is that the value of `CI_BUILD_TOKEN` in the build runner isn't a valid GitLab Private Token - it's only a token to connect to the Docker Registry - as per the documentation.

Is there a way to get a valid GitLab API token that the build runner can use to access the API for the project it's running a build for? Seems like this should be possible.

GitLab Runner:

```
gitlab-runner -v
Version:      1.2.0
Git revision: 3a4fcd4
Git branch:   HEAD
GO version:   go1.6.2
Built:        Sun, 22 May 2016 20:05:30 +0000
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Comment: As mentioned here, do you have gitlab runner 1.2? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468084/what-is-the-special-gitlab-ci-token-user#comment62905945_37545323)

Comment: Yes, I have GitLab 1.2.0 - the linked article is about accessing the Docker Registry, I'm trying to access GitLab's API. Accessing the GitLab Docker Registry does work.

Comment: It seems `CI_BUILD_TOKEN` is mainly for accessing the registry, not for using the GitLab API.

Comment: It would be great if they can include that as a CI variable.

Answer (score 27):

You can have **read-only** access with the API from the runner, but only if you add a header with the **CI_JOB_TOKEN**.

e.g.

```
curl -H "JOB_TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/2828837/repository/tags
```

And **only** when the project is **public** with **everyone has access** from the same project.

If you want access to private projects as well and/or write access, please up-vote [GitLab issue #29566](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/29566) and/or [#41084](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/41084).

As an alternative for the time being, you can create an access token on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens), and add it to the secret variables, under project settings/ci_cd although not really advised to do as your personal access token will be used by everyone who trigger the job.

Comment: Note that the name of this header should be `JOB-TOKEN`, not `JOB_TOKEN`. That is,

    `curl -H "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/2828837/repository/tags`

Comment: Actually, is this even true? I see no indication in the documentation that job tokens are accepted for authentication outside of a [select few endpoints](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#download-the-artifacts-archive).

Comment: @bgamari I just verified my code: `sprintf(headertoken, "JOB_TOKEN: %s",cJSON_get_key(env_json, "CI_JOB_TOKEN"));` , wich I use for publishing https://downloads.odagrun.com/latest/

Comment: Anything that is public will respond to `repository/tags` regardless of token - I don't think the token is doing anything here.

Comment: @Danny it might (still?) work but according to their documentation the header name is indeed `JOB-TOKEN`, not `JOB_TOKEN`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the [Secret Variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/#secret-variables)? You can define in the settings and then use in your build script.